# Percentage padding is not adding up total height correctly

Tags: html, css

So I have a page with `html`, `header`, `body`, `div` tags etc. For the CSS, I have:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  width: 98%;
  height: 98%;
  padding: 1%;
}
```

My issue is there's a scrollbar on the right side of the browser. Meaning the height is too high?

The `html` is set to `100%` height and width. The `body` has a `1%` padding which adds `1%` top, right, bottom and left, so that's `width - 2 = 98` and `height - 2 = 98`.

So padding `1%` height `98%`, and width `98%`. How am I getting a scrollbar?

Comment: That's interesting! Does that also happen if you add `box-sizing: border-box;` to `body`?

Comment: @Johannes no idea what box-sizing does but i fixed it by doing what josh said, use vh and vw

Answer (score 12):

It's not working as expected because the percentage-based `padding` is relative to the width of the element. If you resize the browser so that the height is greater than the width, you will notice that the scrollbar goes away (which is because the `padding` is relative to the width).

According to the spec:

> [**8 Box model - 8.4 Padding properties:**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#padding-properties)
>
> The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the generated box's containing block, even for 'padding-top' and 'padding-bottom'. If the containing block's width depends on this element, then the resulting layout is undefined in CSS 2.1.

One possible work-around is to use viewport-percentage units such as `vw` in order to make the percentage relative to the width:

```
body {
    width: 98%;
    height: 98%;
    padding: 1vh 1vw;
}
```

You could also add [`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) to include the `padding` in the element's dimensions:

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 1%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: you really need to define width and height if you add box-sizing?

Comment: i see thank you, it was kinda weird seeing as common sense tells you that setting html to 100% w/h sets html to fit the whole screen then if you set body with a padding of 1% it takes 1% w/h from html and adds it as a padding to body and giving body 98% w/h fills in for the rest of the page

Comment: Also remember that body comes with 8px of margin out of the box.

Comment: @fauxserious Based on the OP's posted CSS, they were removing the margin.

Comment: yeah i use * to select everything and then i reset it's margin and padding

Answer (score 3):

In CSS, percentage margin and padding is relative to the width of the container, as Josh Crozier has already explained that in his answer.

I suggest to set the percentage padding on the `<html>` element, the root of the document, plus `box-sizing: border-box;` together it gives you the equal space around.

> **`border-box`** Length and percentages values for width and height (and respective min/max properties) on this element determine the
>   border box of the element. That is, any padding or border specified on
>   the element is laid out and drawn inside this specified width and
>   height. The content width and height are calculated by subtracting the
>   border and padding widths of the respective sides from the specified
>   width and height properties. -[W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#propdef-box-sizing)

```css
html {
  background: silver;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5%;
}
body {
  background: pink;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: what does box-sizing exactly do, i read on w3s that it tells the browser what the sizing properties are however i don't fully understand what i means

Comment: Basically, what `border-box` does is - the element will stick with the `width` and `height` that you set, regardless of the `padding` and `border` values.